# CPLEX: Suboptimal Solution

Tags: cplex

I look for an optimal solution is a TSP-like problem (two operators which both can service a subset of locations, objective: MAXIMIZE revenue - cost, sum over both operators; operators only visit a given location, if it increases their total profit, some locations give revenue, if they are not visited). 
If I leave everything open, I get a profit of 384, but if I restrict my problem further (by stating that one of the customers must not be visited by operator 2), it increases to 417.

Some more info about my problem: I use Lazy Constraint Callbacks for Subtour Elimination, as far as I can see, this is no issue. I don't seem to be able to generate a minimal example, the only instance I found this issue has 124 nodes, deleting some makes the problem go away.

In general, however, I believe that a maximization problem should never improve when adding an additional constraint.

What I tried so far (using Java+CPLEX)

- Set number of threads to 1 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1RS02094)
- Replace "addEq" by "add(model.eq)" (seems to conflict with lazy constraints sometimes)

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=065d42c2-9c72-4a18-aa4a-9c29ce863eb7)